# Hiding a print function in python

Tags: python, printing

I am running technical training at my work and each week I take people through the python I am learning.

This week however a long term member of staff is leaving and I want to hide a print(Go to the pub to celebrate ___ leaving) in my code. However I don't want it to be readable as I want people to be trying to understand more complicated code. My first idea is to convert my message to hex and print it after conversion so it's not totally readable. Are there other fun ideas?

The idea is to scare people as if we're going to be doing a really horrible technical session but instead go to the pub. What is the best code I can use to accomplish the goal of obscuring my print and scaring people with code?

**Edit**

Another possible solution is to break PEP8 guidelines, have the text way offscreen?

Comment: you could pass in a monstrous binary code section as input and convert it to your desired output before printing. there should be plenty of converters online. - this will increase the feeling of "technicality" even more :-)

you could even make the `requests`-module have a POST request to a converter website and POST the binary section, retrieve the ASCII text and print it in your program.

Comment: `01001100 01100101 01110100 00100111 01110011 00100000 01100111 01101111 00100000 01110100 01101111 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 00100000 01110000 01110101 01100010 00100000 01100010 01101111 01111001 01110011 00100001` would be `let's go to the pub boys!`. pretty straightforward and easy to have fun with, e.g. by putting all of the sections inside a list, looping through it, popping items out etc.

Answer (score 0):

A fun way to hide text within a program would be to use Ascii values. Your sentence would look something like this. 
071 111 032 116 111 032 116 104 101 032 112 117 098 032 116 111 032 099 101 108 101 098 114 097 116 101 032 095 095 095 032 108 101 097 118 105 110 103
Hope this helps!